# Javascript: pass function by reference, rather than by value

Tags: javascript, function, pointers

If I have

```
var foo = function() {
    console.log('foo');
}, bar = foo;
```

and call `bar()`, the console logs `foo`. If then, I do

```
foo = function() {
    console.log('not foo');
}
```

and call `bar()`, the console still logs `foo`. How can I get around this?

Comment: What *exactly* are you actually trying to accomplish here? Why would you actually need this?

Comment: @MattBurland Nothing. Just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: I think you should read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:JavaScript/Guide/Obsolete_Pages/Defining_Functions

Comment: I guess you could do this: `bar = function() { foo(); }`, which isn't quite what you wanted, but if you now redefine `foo`, calling `bar` will call the new `foo` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you're trying to do is not very wise, but i'll hand you the shotgun, blast off! (your legs i mean.)

```
var foo = function () { console.log("foo"); }
var bar = function () { foo(); }
bar();
var foo = function () { console.log("qux"); }
bar();
```

Comment: Not sure I get it, wouldn't the last call to `bar()` still log `qux`, so foo did change just like in the question ?

Comment: It would indeed, unlike the first call, which would log `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

I would create an object and make a function that i want to copy a property of that object:

```
var obj = {
    bar : function(){ alert 'bar'; }
},
obj2 = obj;
obj.bar = function(){ alert 'foo'; };
```

then

```
obj2.bar()
```

would output 'foo';

Comment: Ah, I never knew objects were passed by reference. But wait, does that work the other way? Does changing `obj2.bar` change `obj.bar`?

Comment: Yes, if you doubt me you can run it yourself.obj2.bar and obj.bar are the same property of object that obj2 and obj reference to.

Comment: I wasn't doubting you, I was asking for clarification regarding a feature that I never knew existed.

Comment: @Bluefire objects are not really passed by reference. Anything in JavaScript that has an object as its value (a variable, parameter, or object property, or in general any expression) really has a *reference* to the object as its value. That's all you can have; unlike C++ there's no such thing as a variable whose value really is an object. Thus, JavaScript is always pass-by-value, but object values are really object *reference* values.