# Javascript: create a fake copy of window to pass functions by reference

Tags: javascript, function, pointers, pass-by-reference

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513816/javascript-pass-function-by-reference-rather-than-by-value), and while I initially found the nested function response suggestion to nest the other function's call in my function's definition more handy, the other answer got me thinking: what if I create a copy of `window`, and use the fact that objects are passed by reference to my advantage, like so:

```
var fakewindow = window,
    foo = function() {
        console.log('foo');
    };

fakewindow.bar = foo;
```

So now, `foo` (which is really `window.foo`) and `bar` (which is really `window.bar`, which is in turn `fakewindow.bar` as `window` and `fakewindow` are the same object) should have the same reference. But they don't:

```
bar(); // logs foo
foo = function() {
    console.log('not foo');
}
bar(); // still logs foo
```

Why is this so?

EDIT for clarification: the aforementioned answer said that objects are passed by reference, and therefore so are their properties, i.e. given this:

```
var obj = {
    bar : function(){ alert 'bar'; }
},
obj2 = obj;
obj.bar = function(){ alert 'foo'; };
```

`obj2.bar()` would log `foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window` is a reference to the window object.
`fakewindow` is a reference to the window object (created by copying the first reference).

`foo` is a reference to a function.
`window.bar` and `fakewindow.bar` are both properties on the same object which are references to the same function (created by copying `foo`).

When you *then* overwrite the value of `foo`, you have a reference to a new function in `foo`. This doesn't change the value of `bar` which continues to be a reference to the previous function.

In short: `bar` is not a reference to `foo` even though they both (at one point) had the same value (which was a reference to a function).

In the diagram below, arrows represent references.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Ah, I see. Didn't realise that D:

Comment: Wait... `When you then overwrite the value of foo, you have a reference to a new function in foo but the old references to the previous function in bar still exist.` How come?

Comment: @Bluefire — Because you don't overwrite the value of `bar`.

Comment: But I thought `bar` pointed to `foo`, i.e. they had the same reference.

Comment: @Bluefire — Their values were both references to the same function. Then you overwrote one of those values with a reference to a new function. Neither variable referenced the other variable. See the diagram in the answer.

Comment: But why? Since `window` references `fakewindow`, then `fakewindow.bar` must also reference `bar` (which is `window.bar`). Then, if `foo` references `fakewindow.bar`, which in turn references `bar`, then surely `foo` must reference `bar`.

Comment: **You cannot reference a variable.** Only an object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56605/discussion-between-bluefire-and-quentin).

Comment: `window` references the window object. `fakewindow` is a copy of `window` so also references the window object. `bar` is a property of the window object so `anyReferenceToTheWindowObject.bar` will give you the same value. There is never a reference to `foo` or `bar`.

Comment: When `foo` is created, it is assigned a reference to a function as a value. That value is copied to `bar` so `bar` also has a reference to the same function. Then the value of `foo` is overwritten. `foo` now has a value that is a reference to a different function. `bar`'s value is unchanged and still has a reference to the original function.

Comment: All this is in the answer already, expressed in text and a diagram. I don't think I can explain it differently if neither of those approaches are working for you.

Answer (score 1):

foo and bar are both variables referencing the same function. When you run the code:

```
foo = function() {
    console.log('not foo');
}
```

you're changing the reference of foo to a new function, but bar still refers to the old function which prints out 'foo'.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you haven't updated your `bar` variable to point to the new `foo` function.

Here is an easier example using numbers:

```
var x = 5; // x === 5
var y = x; // y === x === 5
x = 6;     // x === 6
y;         // y === 5
```

In order to update `y` to now equal `6` you'd need to once again call:

```
y = x;
```

When specifying `bar = foo` you're assigning the *value* of `foo` as the value of `bar`. You're not assigning `foo` to `bar`.

Comment: I understand that. If you read my previous, linked question, you will see that, and the fact that this is what I do **not** want to happen.

Comment: @Bluefire if you want `bar` to be equal to your new `foo` function you'll need to once again specify `fakewindow.bar = foo;`.

Comment: If you want your answer to be correct you'll need to once again read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do

```
foo = function() {
    console.log('not foo');
}
```

you don't modify existing function (which is currently assigned to bar and foo) but you create a **new** function and assign this function to foo. If you want to do what you are trying to achieve you can try smth like this:

```
var foo = {func: function() { console.log("foo"); };
foo.func(); // print "foo"
var bar = foo;
bar.func = function() { console.log("not foo"); };
bar.func(); // print "not foo"
foo.func(); // print "not foo"
```